# Possible CORS issue. What's going on and how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors, intermine

I'm accessing a REST web service, using an asynchronous request to load query data. When I run the same code on a different server (e.g. I develop locally and then visit a version that is live on the web), the AJAX request will fail. Clear the cache, refresh the page, and it'll work.

The error I get (copy/pasted from the chrome console, also happens in FF) when it fails is:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.flymine.org/query/service/model?format=json. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://null.jsbin.com' is therefore not allowed access. im.js:129
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'content-type' of undefined http://www.flymine.org/query/service/summaryfields?format=json.
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' that is not equal to the supplied origin.  
 Origin 'http://null.jsbin.com' is therefore not allowed access. im.js:129 
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'content-type' of undefined
```

**This is pretty easy to reproduce:**

1. Visit the code [on one server (JSBin)](http://jsbin.com/tiqolis/8/edit?html,console). You should get successful output stating the number of exons the query returned.
2. Visit the same code [on a different server (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/yochannah/r81rtung/1/). If using chrome, ensure that your developer tools are closed, as they tend to clear the cache for you and could prevent the error happening. The output pane should shown an error, until you clear the cache and run the jsfiddle again.

I'm pretty sure that there is something CORS-ey going on that I need to enable, but I'm not entirely sure what it might be. I do have access to modify server headers etc. as needed to prevent this issue.

There's a library, [IMJS](https://github.com/alexkalderimis/imjs), doing most of the work for the communication, but **here's the basic code for the connection:**

```
  var flymine   = new imjs.Service({root: 'www.flymine.org/query'});
  var query     = {
    from: 'Gene',
    select: [
      'exons.symbol',
      'chromosome.primaryIdentifier',
      'exons.chromosomeLocation.start',
      'exons.chromosomeLocation.end'
    ],
    where: {
      symbol: 'eve',
      organism: {lookup: 'D. melanogaster'}}
  };
  flymine.rows(query).then(function(rows) {
    console.log("No. of exons: " + rows.length);
    rows.forEach(function printRow(row) {
      console.log("[" + row[0] + "] " + row[1] + ":" + row[2] + ".." + row[3]);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message pretty much spells out the problem for you:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.flymine.org/query/service/model?format=json.

The server you are trying to access is `www.flymine.org`

> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://fiddle.jshell.net'

`www.flymine.org` says that `http://fiddle.jshell.net` is allowed to read the data from it.

`www.flymine.org` does this by putting an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response.

> that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://null.jsbin.com' is therefore not allowed access. im.js:129

You are making the request from `http://null.jsbin.com` and not `http://fiddle.jshell.net`.

You need to change `www.flymine.org` so it gives permission to `http://null.jsbin.com`.